# Accessing backend endpoints but unable to access frontend code after successful deployment in Railway

Tags: angular, nestjs, devops, railway

I deployed a Nestjs and Angular app in Railway.app via dockerfile. My problem is after deploying the app successfully, I'm getting access the backend's endpoints but can't access any frontend part code. I used nx monorepo where my Backend running on port 3000 via PM2 and frontend running 5173 via Vite.

Can you please help me on this? Or am I missing some configuration related things.

TIA

Here is an demo URL for backend https://fullstack-app-production.up.railway.app/api/products

In that link I'm successfully getting product response. Now, How can I get the frontend which is running in port 5173 ? I tried with https://fullstack-app-production.up.railway.app:5173 but it doesn't work at all.